# DropNet GetDeltaAsync not working

Tags: asp.net, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropnet

I am using the very latest DropNet and I am unable to get the changed files in my dropbox account.  It fails every time.  I have many files in the root and I have a subfolder of SB which I would like to check for changes; however if I could get GetDeltaAsync to work that would be a start. The _client call is working fine. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
Dim token As String = "2R-XXXXX"
    Dim _client = New DropNetClient("e5adXXX", "xqb05fXXXX", token)

Try
    _client.GetDeltaAsync(True, "/", AddressOf AccountInfo_Success, AddressOf AccountInfo_Fail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: "It fails every time." It would help if you said whether there's an exception, which (if any) of your callbacks are invoked, what they receive, anything else you've tried to debug or fix the problem so far, etc.

Comment: Hi smarx,  I believe it has something to do with the prefix (path).  If I use GetDelta with my "/SB" path I can see the files in delta.Entries (via a loop) and then I see if the rev is different than what I have in the database, if true then pull latest file.  If I use GetDeltaAsync the "/" or "/SB" returns null. Documentation  on GetDeltaAsync is thin, so I wanted to see what it would return.  So I am not sure if it will really save me the rev comparison step.